# Sharepoint PeoplePicker in custom asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Is it possible to use Sharepoint PeoplePicker functionality in a custom ASP.Net project?

How?

Comment: is this a provider hosted app?  or a truly raw asp.net solution?  are you pulling the source of users/groups from active directory or another source and just want the same look and feel?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, it´s raw asp.net solution. I want to pull users from Active Directory. I don´t care about form to be honest, just need funcionality to pull information from Active Directory